# How can I disable all ESLint rule checking temporarily?

Tags: cypress, eslint

Existing answers about disabling ESLint answer the question "How can I disable ESLint in one file, a pattern of files, or a directory of files?" Is there an easy way to just stop a project from checking ESLint at all?

My goal here is to run a Cypress test with a `debugger;` command and possibly many other syntax errors due to temporary commenting out. I want to be able to test partially complete code and then toggle type checking back on. Bonus points if the solution stops TypeScript checking as well.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- adding `/* eslint-disable */` to `cypress/support/e2e.js`
- launching `cypress open` with `DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true`

My app is using create-react-app.

Comment: My advice: Don't do that. Even if you have code commented out, it should still be valid eslint and valid TS syntax. Otherwise it will only lead to bad code in the future. Even tough you tell yourself that this won't happen.

Comment: Actually most of it is commented out *because* of ESLint -- it's pasted in but not yet called or with missing imports. I want linting on at all times except when I need to run the half-working code so I can see the problems with the non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this, you can disable the `no-debugger` rule in development but leave it on in production, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/62592912/733092:

```
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'warn'
```

Another workaround is to put the per-file disable text in a PyCharm Live Template so you can auto-type

```
/* eslint-disable */
// @ts-nocheck
```

at the top of the file you're in.